# Imprimir el máximo entre un conjunto de variables utilizando if y strings en Python

Tags: python, string, revisión-de-código, condiciones

Supongamos que tengo 3 números cualquiera alojados en tres variables distintas:

```
x= 5
y= 11
z= 37
```

La prueba que realiza el if es determinar que las 3 variables sean impares. Si es así, da los mensajes "Los tres números son impares" y "El mayor es" seguido del número correspondiente.

```
if x %2!=0 and y %2!=0 and z %2!=0:
    print("Los tres números son impares")
    print("El mayor es",  max(x,y,z))
elif x %2!=0 or y %2!=0 or z %2!=0:
    print("Al menos uno es par")
else:
    print("Todos son pares")
```

Lo que deseo es que el segundo print para el if regrese un mensaje como el siguiente, tomando en cuenta los valores que asigné en un principio:

```
"El mayor es 37 y corresponde a la variable z"
```

Por supuesto, la idea es que el print devuelva, para cualquier caso, el mayor número y su correspondiente variable. Entiendo que esto podría hacerse utilizando diccionarios, pero deseo que la solución se ciña a los requerimientos que he comentado.
De antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Si solo tienes esas tres variables una aproximación simple es usar condicionales, dentro o fuera de la propia llamada a `print`:

```
x= 5
y= 11
z= 37


if x %2!=0 and y %2!=0 and z %2!=0:
    print("Los tres números son impares")
    m = max((x,  y,  z))
    print("El mayor es {1}  y corresponde a la variable {0}".format("x" if m == x
                                                                    else "y" if m == y
                                                                    else "z",  m))
elif x %2!=0 or y %2!=0 or z %2!=0:
    print("Al menos uno es par")
else:
    print("Todos son pares")
```

Se usa el operador ternario dentro de `str.format` pero podrías implementarlo en un bloque `if-elif-else` antes de imprimir.

Si lo quieres todo metido en el `print` puedes hacer esto:

```
print("El mayor es {}  y corresponde a la variable {}".format(*((x, "x") if x == max(x,  y,  z)
                                                                  else (y, "y") if y == max(x,  y,  z)
                                                                  else (z, "z"))))
```

o bién:

```
print("El mayor es {}  y corresponde a la variable {}".format(*((x, "x") if x >= z and x >= y
                                                                else (y, "y") if y > z
                                                                else (z, "z"))))
```

Muy poco legible pero funciona...

---

Aunque no quieras usar diccionarios, es posiblemente una solución más escalable, para ello usa un diccionario y el argumento `key` de `max`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> x= 5
>>> y= 11
>>> z= 37

>>> d=dict(x=x, y=y, z=z)
>>> max(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
('z', 37)
```

Esto retorna la tupla con la pareja `(key, value`) que se corresponde con el máximo valor.

Implementado en tu código:

```
from operator import itemgetter

x= 5
y= 11
z= 37

d=dict(x=x, y=y, z=z)

if x %2!=0 and y %2!=0 and z %2!=0:
    print("Los tres números son impares")
    print("El mayor es {1}  y corresponde a la variable {0}".format(*max(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))))
elif x %2!=0 or y %2!=0 or z %2!=0:
    print("Al menos uno es par")
else:
    print("Todos son pares")
```

**Salida:**

> Los tres números son impares
>   El mayor es 37  y corresponde a la variable z

---

**Edición:**

- Puedes mirarte el funcionamiento `str.format` y del *Format Specification Mini-Language* en la documentación oficial, junto a múltiples ejemplos (en inglés):

  [6.1.3. Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

  Básicamente este método lo que hace es realizar una operación de formato en la cadena. La cadena en la que se llama este método puede contener texto literal o campos de reemplazo delimitados por llaves {}. Devuelve una copia de la cadena donde cada campo de reemplazo se reemplaza con el valor o valores que se le pasan como argumentos.

  Cada campo de reemplazo puede contener un índice numérico para determinar en que lugar va cada argumento:

  ```
  >>> cad = "¡Hola {}!".format("Python")
  >>> cad
  '¡Hola Python!'
  ```

  Permite realizar formateos mucho más complejos, número de decimales, impresión o no de signos de números, tabulación de datos, alineación, cambios de bases numéricas al imprimir, etc.
- El operador `*`  se limita a desempaquetar argumentos de una tupla/lista. `mifunción(4, "hola")` es "equivalente" a `mifunción(*(4, "hola"))` o a `mifunción(*[4, "hola"])`.
- La sintaxis `A if x else B if y else C` es la sintaxis propia del [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario). Retorna `A` si se cumple `x`, sino retorna `B` si `y` es cierta o si nada se cumple retorna `C`. Otro ejemplo real:

  ```
  >>> a = 3
  >>> b = 4
  >>> "Mayor" if a > b else "Menor" if a < b else "Iguales"
  "Menor"
  ```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! ¿Dónde puedo documentarme respecto a este segmento de código que utilizaste? .format(*((x, "x") if x == max(x,  y,  z)
                                                                  else (y, "y") if y == max(x,  y,  z)
                                                                  else (z, "z"))))

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera he editado la pregunta añadiendo al final una explicación más detallada de lo que se usa en esa línea. Mira a ver que tal. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de JSevilla en particular usando un diccionario creo que es la óptima. De todas formas quiero agregar algo más. Lo que quieres hacer es básicamente identificar una variable por medio de su valor, esto si bien es posible, es absolutamente ambiguo, supongamos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
a = 3
b = 3
```

Si pudiéramos identificar la variable a la que "apunta" el valor `3`. ¿Cuál sería? ¿La variable `a` o la variable `b`?. Es decir, se puede relacionar una variable a un valor de manera unívoca pero no al revés. Teniendo en cuenta este problema y solo a titulo informativo hay una forma de obtener el nombre de una variable a partir de un valor no recomendable para usarlo si no tenemos bien claro las limitaciones relacionadas.

```
x= 5
y= 11
z= 3
maximo, variable = [v for v in list(locals().items()) if v[1] == max(x, y, z)][0]
print("El valor máximo es {1} y corresponde a la variable '{0}'".format(maximo, variable))
> El valor máximo es 11 y corresponde a la variable 'y'
```

Haciendo uso de [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#locals) accedemos a un diccionario con la tabla de símbolos del ámbito local, el cual dependerá desde dónde invoquemos la función.

Esto tiene su limitación que es muy clara cuando ocurre esto:

```
otra_variable = 11

x= 5
y= 11
z= 3

maximo, variable = [v for v in list(locals().items()) if v[1] == max(x, y, z)][0]

print("El valor máximo es {1} y corresponde a la variable '{0}'".format(maximo, variable))
> El valor máximo es 11 y corresponde a la variable 'otra_variable'
```